# C# model is not supporting sql query because of GUID

Tags: c#, sql-server, guid

In database, my user_details table has "UserId (varchar 255)". My model is as following:

```
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
```

The problem is When I querying it by UserId, I am getting invalid cast exception regarding string to guid conversion.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE UserId = '" + new Guid(userId.ToString()) +     "'"
```

Comment: Use parameters, you will get better performance from sql-server.

Comment: What's the value of userId? If you're getting a cast exception, .NET is saying it's not a guid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on the anomaly on Database table declaration. As I mentioned in question, My DB table UserId field was varchar, that was causing the problem When I changed that to uniqueidentifier, it stated working.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott mentioned (and considering there is no mention of an ORM that is doing the parameterization for you), use parameters, both for better security and better performance.

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE UserId = @UserId";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
    command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = userId.ToString();

    // Execute query and return data
}
```

For completeness, if you simply wanted to convert your userId inline (resembling what you're currently doing), you could use the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE UserId = '" + userId.ToString() +  "'"
```

However, I'd strongly recommend against it.  In this case you have a Guid type so you should be safe from Sql Injection, but writing code like this will help you form bad habits and potentially create issues down the road.  My first example is the recommended approach.

Answer (score -1):

I think that in your table you should declare [UserId] as [Uniqueindetifier] that is the same that GUID [Global Unique Identifier], and in the select query just send the Unique Identifier as string inside quotes like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE UserId = '" + UserId.ToString() + "'"
```

Or

Don't intance a new Guid object in the query, cause the query is just a simple string, you cant parce object in a query:

Change this:

```
"SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE UserId = '" + new Guid(userId.ToString()) + "'"
```

For this:

```
"SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE UserId = '" + userId.ToString() +  "'"
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to use like this:

```
SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE UserId = '" + Giud.UserId + "'"
```

and choose a type for UserId..int for example

**UPDATE**

```
public Guid {
  public static string UserId {get;set;}
  public static string Email {get;set;}
  public static string Gender {get;set;}
}
```

Then, for example if you have a textBox, the text you'll insert will be stored in `Guid.UserId`. Than you cand make the query like I said above.

Comment: So you want to select from database where `UserId` is equal with `UserId`  from your form?

Comment: Well, you can use like this. In 2 minute I will update my answer.

Comment: What on earth is this supposed to actually do?  Other than closely resemble an answer that would prime the OP for sql injection?

Comment: He didn't asked about security, I gave him what he asked for and what I think he wants. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: When did he ask for a custom Guid class? He's trying to use System.Guid not create his own class. You told him the answer is UserId should be an int. how does that help him use Guids?